# Pagination query mysql+php take 20-40 seconds

Tags: php, mysql, indexing

Hi I have pagination in angular js in my app, I send the data to my big query that includes the filters that the user set

UPDATE
SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS   this is my problem. How do I count the rows of specific filters . It is took me 2 second for 100,000 rows  I need the number for the pagination  as a total number

UPDATE:
I have the following inner query that I missed here :

(select count(*) from students as inner_st where st.name = inner_st.name) as names,

when I remove above inner query is much faster

rows: 50,000
Users table : 4 rows
Classes table : 4 rows
indexes: only id as primary key

query time 20-40 seconds

```
tables: students.

columns : id, date ,class, name,image,status,user_id,active 

table user
coloumn: id,full_name,is_admin
```

query

```
SELECT  SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS st.id, 
        st.date,
        st.image,
        st.user_id,
        st.status,
        st, 
        ck.name AS class_name,
        users.full_name,
        (select count(*) from students AS inner_st where st.name = inner_st.name) AS names,
FROM students AS st
    LEFT JOIN  users ON st.user_id = users.user_id
    LEFT JOIN  classes AS ck  ON st.class = ck.id
WHERE date BETWEEN '2018-01-17' AND DATE_ADD('2018-01-17', INTERVAL 1 DAY)
    AND DATE_FORMAT(date,'%H:%i') >= '00:00'
    AND DATE_FORMAT(date,'%H:%i') <= '23:59'
    AND st.active=1 
    -- here I can concat filters from  web like "and class= 1"
ORDER BY st.date DESC
LIMIT  0, 10
```

How can I make it faster? when I delete the order by and SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS it faster but i need them 
I heard about indexes but only primary key is index

Comment: It's hard to tell without knowing how many rows are in your tables, which columns are indexed.

Comment: @JoeP.  hi - id as primary key and 50000 rows

Comment: Add the alias of `st`.  Tell us which table(s) the extra filter columns will be in.  (It makes a _big_difference in optimizing.)  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: @RickJames
I have updated the question I have another inner query when I removed it faster, how can I index that? (select count(*) from students as inner_st where st.name = inner_st.name) as names,

Comment: 1. Convert all joins to inner joins. 2. Make indexes on user_id,class, and date in student table.

Answer (score 1):

Few comments before recommending a different approach to this query:

- Did you consider removing `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` and instead running two queries (one that counts and one that selects the data)? In some cases it might be quicker than joining them both to one query.
- What is the goal of these conditions? What are you trying to achieve? Can we remove them (as it seems they might always return true?) - `AND DATE_FORMAT(st.date, '%H:%i') >= '00:00' AND DATE_FORMAT(st.date, '%H:%i') <= '23:59'`
- You only need 10 results, but the database will have to run the "names" subquery for each of the results before the LIMIT (which might be a lot?). Therefore, I would recommend to extract the subquery from the SELECT clause to a temporary table, index it and join to it (see fixed query below).

To optimize the query, let's begin with adding these indexes:

```
ALTER TABLE `classes` ADD INDEX `classes_index_1` (`id`, `name`);
ALTER TABLE `students` ADD INDEX `students_index_1` (`active`, `user_id`, `class`, `name`, `date`);
ALTER TABLE `users` ADD INDEX `users_index_1` (`user_id`, `full_name`);
```

Now create the temporary table (originally this was a subquery in the SELECT clause) and index it:

```
-- Transformed subquery to a temp table to improve performance
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temp1 AS SELECT
        count(*) AS names,
        name 
    FROM
        students AS inner_st 
    WHERE
        1 = 1 
    GROUP BY
        name 
    ORDER BY
        NULL

-- This index is required for optimal temp tables performance
ALTER TABLE
  `temp1`
ADD
  INDEX `temp1_index_1` (`name`, `names`);
```

And the modified query:

```
SELECT
        SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS st.id,
        st.date,
        st.image,
        st.user_id,
        st.status,
        ck.name AS class_name,
        users.full_name,
        temp1.names 
    FROM
        students AS st 
    LEFT JOIN
        users 
            ON st.user_id = users.user_id 
    LEFT JOIN
        classes AS ck 
            ON st.class = ck.id 
    LEFT JOIN
        temp1 
            ON st.name = temp1.name 
    WHERE
        st.date BETWEEN '2018-01-17' AND DATE_ADD('2018-01-17', INTERVAL 1 DAY) 
        AND st.active = 1 
    ORDER BY
        st.date DESC LIMIT 0,
        10
```

Comment: thanks  SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS   this is my problem. How do I count the rows of specific filters . It is took me 2 second for 100,000 rows  I need the number for the pagination

Comment: @Guz - I'm not sure I understood your question. Can you please clarify? Are you asking for an alternative for SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS because it's what slows down your query?

Comment: yes , what can I do alternative to that function . And I have to use that number

Comment: @Guz - you can decide to split the work to two queries, so one of them will be a count(*) of the same query logic, which will be executed once and will return you the number you're looking for. You can read more information about the performance comparison between SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS and COUNT(*) here: https://www.percona.com/blog/2007/08/28/to-sql_calc_found_rows-or-not-to-sql_calc_found_rows/

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try first:

```
INDEX(active, date)
```

Is `user_id` the PK for `users`?  Is `class_id` the PK for `classes`?  If not, then they should be `INDEXed`.

Why are you testing the times separate?

Fix the test so it is obvious which table each column is in.

Do you really need `LEFT JOIN`?  Or would `JOIN` suffice?  In the latter case, there are more optimization options.

Give some realistic examples of other `SELECTs`; different index(es) may be needed.

Is the "first" page slow?  Or only later pages?  See [*this*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pagination) for pagination optimization -- by *not* using `OFFSET`.

Comment: user_id and class are not PK. Just id that fit to users and classes table   . I tried the indexes you wrote .still slowly.  I guess I can remove the join /left join from here but the class table hold 4 rows  and users 2 rows

Comment: I have updated the question i have another inner query when I removed it faster, how can I index that?


 (select count(*) from students as inner_st where st.name = inner_st.name) as names,

Comment: `users`: `INDEX(user_id)` and `classes`: `INDEX(class_id)`

Comment: @Guz - That needs `INDEX(name)` if it is not already the `PRIMARY KEY`.

Comment: I move that subquery to join and improved the performance a lot , but indexes dont help me at all , maybe 0.1 seconds

Comment: @Guz - Please edit your Question to show the current formulation of the query, plus the current indexes.

Comment: Write @Rick  thanks  SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS   this is my problem. How do I count the rows of specific filters . It is took me 2 second for 100,000 rows  I need the number for the pagination

Comment: @Guz - You may _want_ `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS`, but I question whether you _need_ it.  Notice how most search engines first went to "about", then abandoned giving any clue of the total?

Comment: What is the alternative . I need that number to show the total and to calculate pagination number

Comment: If you are trying to find the "last page", simply call it `[Last]` and postpone the computation until the user actually asks for it. Furthermore, you can write a better query to find the "last page" than to scan through the entire dataset to find the Nth page (after doing a full scan to compute `N`).

Comment: Hi @Rick can you share me an example for that?

Comment: Seems like changing `DESC` to `ASC` would get you the oldest 10 rows.